# Check the convergence of double sum

Tags: summation, series-expansion, asymptotics, convergence

I have the following double summations:

Sum 1 : $\sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{(p+1) \Gamma \left(p+\frac{11}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (p+2)}}}{(p+2) \sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}-\sum _{j=p+2}^k \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\Gamma \left(j+\frac{7}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (j+1)}}}{\sqrt{j} (j+1) \sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}\right)$

Sum 2: $\sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{(p+1) \Gamma \left(p+\frac{11}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (p+2)}}}{(p+2) \sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}-\sum _{j=p+2}^k \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\Gamma \left(j+\frac{7}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (j+1)}}}{\sqrt{j} (j+1) \sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}\right)^2$

I empirically (and analytically) verified that Sum 1 converges as $k \to \infty$ but it wasn't clear whether Sum 2 converges.

I want to check the same using Mathematica. I tried using `SumConvergence` but it displayed the same output as input.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

**Edit - 1:** Mathematica Input Forms:

`Sum[(Sqrt[(p + 1)*(Gamma[11/4 + p]/(Gamma[11/4] * Gamma[2 + p]))]/(p + 2)) - Sum[ Sqrt[Gamma[7/4 + j]/(Gamma[11/4]*Gamma[1 +j])]/(Sqrt[j]*(j + 1)), {j,p + 2, k}] , {p, 0, k - 1}]`

`Sum[((Sqrt[(p + 1)*(Gamma[11/4 + p]/(Gamma[11/4] * Gamma[2 + p]))]/(p + 2)) - Sum[ Sqrt[Gamma[7/4 + j]/(Gamma[11/4]*Gamma[1 +j])]/(Sqrt[j]*(j + 1)), {j,p + 2, k}])^2 , {p, 0, k - 1}]`

**Edit 2:** Some background about this expression based on @user64494 answer:

---

I have a random walk with the following expression

$S = \frac{1}{2}  x_0+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}   \sqrt{1+\frac{r}{2}} \left(x_1-\frac{x_0}{2}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})} \left(x_2-\frac{x_0+x_1}{3}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{4}}{5}  \sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})(1+\frac{r}{4})} \left(x_3-\frac{x_0+x_1+x_2}{4}\right) + \dots$

with $0<r<1$ and $x_0,x_1,x_2, \dots $ are sampled independently from Gaussian distribution with mean $1$ and variance $1$. I want to show that $\Bbb{E}(S)$ and $Var(S)$ are finite.

---

To see that Sum 1 converges, consider the following:

Let $r = 0.75$ and let $x_0 = x_1 = x_2 \dots = 1$.

Then $S = \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\Pi_{j=2}^{(p+1)} (1+\frac{0.75}{j}) }}{\sqrt{(p+1)}{(p+2)}} $

Now, `Product[1 + (3/(4*j)), {j, 2, p + 1}]` is $\frac{\Gamma \left(p+\frac{11}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right) \Gamma (p+2)}$ which, after taking the square-root, is $O(p^{3/8})$ as $p \to \infty$. Therefore, each term in the above series is $O(p^{-9/8})$ and hence the series converges.

Now Sum 1 follows from rearranging $S$ by collecting each $x_i$ separately and setting $r = 0.75$ and let $x_0 = x_1 = x_2 \dots = 1$.

This can be seen as follows -

$S = \frac{1}{2}  x_0+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}   \sqrt{1+\frac{r}{2}} \left(x_1-\frac{x_0}{2}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})} \left(x_2-\frac{x_0+x_1}{3}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{4}}{5}  \sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})(1+\frac{r}{4})} \left(x_3-\frac{x_0+x_1+x_2}{4}\right) + \dots + \frac{\sqrt{k}}{k+1}  \sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})(1+\frac{r}{4})\dots(1+\frac{r}{k})} \left(x_{k-1}-\frac{x_0+x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{k-2}}{k}\right)$

By collecting the $x_i$'s separately, we have

$S = x_0\left(\frac{1}{2} - \left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{r}{2}}}{\sqrt{2}\times 3} +\frac{\sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})}}{\sqrt{3}\times 4} +  \frac{\sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})(1+\frac{r}{4})}}{\sqrt{4}\times 5} + \dots \right) \right) + x_1\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}  \sqrt{1+\frac{r}{2}}   - \left(\frac{\sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})}}{\sqrt{3}\times 4} +  \frac{\sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})(1+\frac{r}{4})}}{\sqrt{4}\times 5} + \dots \right) \right) + x_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}  \sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})}   - \left(  \frac{\sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})(1+\frac{r}{4})}}{\sqrt{4}\times 5} + \dots \right) \right) + \dots + x_{k-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k+1}  \sqrt{(1+\frac{r}{2})(1+\frac{r}{3})\dots(1+\frac{r}{k})}   \right)$

i.e. $S = \sum_{p=0}^{k-1} x_p\left(\frac{\sqrt{p+1}}{p+2}\sqrt{\Pi_{i=2}^{p+1}(1+\frac{r}{i}) } - \left(\sum_{j=p+2}^{k} \frac{\sqrt{\Pi_{i=2}^{j}(1+\frac{r}{i}) }}{\sqrt{j}(j+1)}   \right) \right) $

Now, substitute $r=3/4$ and $x_0 = x_1 = \dots = 1$; compute the two products - a) `Product[1 + (3/(4*i)), {i, 2, p + 1}]` = $\frac{\Gamma \left(p+\frac{11}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right) \Gamma (p+2)}$ and b) `Product[1 + (3/(4 i)), {i, 2, j}]` = $\frac{\Gamma \left(j+\frac{7}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right) \Gamma (j+1)}$.

Hence we have $ S = \sum_{p=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac{\sqrt{p+1}}{p+2}\sqrt{ \frac{\Gamma \left(p+\frac{11}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right) \Gamma (p+2)} } - \left(\sum_{j=p+2}^{k} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\Gamma \left(j+\frac{7}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right) \Gamma (j+1)}}}{\sqrt{j}(j+1)}   \right) \right)$

The reason I am rearranging in the form of Sum 1 is because I want to check for the convergence of Variance, which is closely related to Sum 2, which in turn is related to Sum 1.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Mathematica code (`InputForm`) for these sums so that it can be copied and pasted into a notebook.

Comment: @BobHanlon : Thank you for pointing it. I added them.

Comment: `Series[Sqrt[
   Gamma[7/4 + j]/(Gamma[11/4]*Gamma[1 + j])]/(Sqrt[j]*(j + 1)), {j, 
  Infinity, 2}]` results in $$O\left(\left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^{17/8}\right)+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^{9/8}}{\sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}.$$

Comment: Can you explain the relation beween $S = \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\Pi_{j=2}^{(p+1)} (1+\frac{0.75}{j}) }}{\sqrt{(p+1)}{(p+2)}}$ in your Edit 2 and Sum 1, giving us details? TIA.

Comment: @user64494: Thank you for your comments. May I request to kindly not delete your existing answer in future because it brings out well the crux of this problem.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your explanation. In particular, I don't see the summand as the difference. I will be waiting for a rich in content reply of you.

Comment: In addition, I don't see any `p` in $S$.

Comment: @user64494 Added details

Comment: Thank you. You wrote ", `Product[1 + (3/(4*j)), {j, 2, p + 1}]` is $\frac{\Gamma \left(p+\frac{11}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right) \Gamma (p+2)}$ which is $O(p^{3/8})$ as $p\to\infty$". Unfortunately, `Series[Gamma[11/4 + p]/(Gamma[11/4] Gamma[2 + p]), {p, Infinity, 2}]` results in $$\frac{p^{3/4}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}+\frac{45 \sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{p}}}{32 \Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}-\frac{647 \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{5/4}}{2048 \Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{9/4}\right) .$$

Comment: @user64494 - Thanks for pointing the typo. After taking the square root,  $p^{3/4}$ becomes $p^{3/8}$ - edited in the question

Comment: @user64494 - I added a proof that Sum 2 converges. Can you please see if that's correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Despite your claim, Sum 1 diverges. Here are my arguments. First,

```
Series[Sqrt[Gamma[7/4 + j]/(Gamma[11/4]*Gamma[1 + j])]/(Sqrt[j]*(j+ 1)), {j,Infinity,2}]
```

> $$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^{9/8}}{\sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^{17/8}\right) $$

Second,

```
AsymptoticSum[(1/j)^(9/8)/Sqrt[Gamma[11/4]],{j,p+2,k},k -> Infinity, Assumptions-> p>0]
```

> `HurwitzZeta[9/8, 2 + p]/Sqrt[Gamma[11/4]]`

Third,

```
Series[(Sqrt[(p + 1)*(Gamma[11/4 + p]/(Gamma[11/4]*Gamma[2 + p]))]/(p + 2)) - 
HurwitzZeta[9/8, 2 + p]/Sqrt[Gamma[11/4]], p -> Infinity]
```

> $$-\frac{7 \sqrt[8]{\frac{1}{p}}}{\sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{9/8}\right) $$

If I am not mistaken, the latest result implies the divergence of Sum 1 as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: Calculations confirm the divegence: for `k=100` Sum 1 equals `2.7`, for `k=200` - `3.00`, for `k=300` - `3.16`.

Comment: For `k=400` Sum  1 equals `3.22`.

Comment: I don't know if one can simply 'confirm' divergence or convergence of a series by simply summing it upto large values and then eyeballing the values. Please cite any rigorous sources for this technique, I am curious. Thanks.

Comment: @honeybadge: You are right, but the series `Sum[p^(-9/8),{p,1,k}]` converges with the rate `k^(-1/8)`. Unfortunately `Table[N[(1/k)^(1/8) /. k -> n], {n, 100, 400, 100}]` results in `{0.562341, 0.515669, 0.490185, 0.472871}` showing a faster rate, than the direct calculations do.

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt to prove that Sum 2 also converges.

Let Sum 1 i.e.  $\sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{(p+1) \Gamma \left(p+\frac{11}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (p+2)}}}{(p+2) \sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}-\sum _{j=p+2}^k \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\Gamma \left(j+\frac{7}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (j+1)}}}{\sqrt{j} (j+1) \sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}\right)$ be written as $\sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \left(A_p - \sum _{j=p+2}^k B_j \right)$

\begin{align}
\sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \left(A_p - \sum _{j=p+2}^k B_j \right) &= \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} A_p - \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \sum _{j=p+2}^k B_j \\
&= \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} A_p - \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \sum _{j=0}^k \Bbb{1}_{(p+2\leq j)}B_j \\
&= \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} A_p -  \sum _{j=0}^k \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \Bbb{1}_{(p+2\leq j)}B_j \qquad \text{$\Bbb{1}$ is the indicator function}\\
&= \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} A_p -  \sum _{j=0}^k B_j (j-1)_{+} \qquad \text{$(.)_{+}$ means only non -ve values}\\
&= \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \left( A_p -  pB_{p+1}  \right) \qquad \text{Substituting $j-1 =p$ } \tag{1}\label{1}\\
&= \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \left( \frac{\sqrt{\frac{(p+1) \Gamma \left(p+\frac{11}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (p+2)}}}{(p+2) \sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}} -  p\frac{\sqrt{\frac{ \Gamma \left(p+\frac{11}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (p+2)}}}{(p+2)\sqrt{(p+1)} \sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}  \right) \\
&= \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{ \Gamma \left(p+\frac{11}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (p+2)}}}{(p+2) \sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}} \left( \sqrt{p+1} -  \frac{p}{\sqrt{(p+1)} }  \right) \\
&= \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{ \Gamma \left(p+\frac{11}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (p+2)}}}{(p+2) \sqrt{(p+1)\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}  \\
&= \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} O(p^{-9/8})  \tag{2}\label{2}\\
\end{align}

From \ref{1} and \ref{2}, we can say that $A_p - \sum _{j=p+2}^k B_j = O(p^{-9/8})$

Now Sum2 is equal to $\sum _{p=0}^{k-1} \left(A_p - \sum _{j=p+2}^k B_j \right)^2 = \sum _{p=0}^{k-1} O(p^{-18/8})$, which converges.